# remove the bit per bit log of wget

Tags: logs, wget

I have a php script that generates bash commands to wget files. I am trying to log wget activity using this:

`--directory-prefix='xxx' --append-output='xxx.txt' -c -t0 -S"`

But the log is too big due to this:

```
 0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  110K 14m5s
50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  230K 10m24s
100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  272K 8m49s
150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 41.7K 15m53s
200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  173M 12m42s
.
.
.
92800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%  156K 0s
92850K .......... .......... ...                             100%  139K=7m56s
```

Can I remove the output above and let wget to only get this:

```
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2015-03-14 20:10:22--  xxxx
Resolving xxxx... xxxx
Connecting to xxxx|xxxx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  Server: nginx/1.4.4
  Date: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 12:09:58 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 194
  Connection: keep-alive
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="xxxx"
Reusing existing connection to xxxx:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.4.4
  Date: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 12:09:58 GMT
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Length: 95102657
  Last-Modified: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 04:54:04 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "5312b96c-5ab26c1"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
Length: 95102657 (91M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `xxxx.mkv'
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2015-03-14 20:10:22--  xxxx
Resolving xxxx... xxxx
Connecting to xxxx|xxxx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  Server: nginx/1.4.4
  Date: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 12:09:58 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 194
  Connection: keep-alive
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="xxxx"
Reusing existing connection to xxxx:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.4.4
  Date: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 12:09:58 GMT
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Length: 95102657
  Last-Modified: Sun, 02 Mar 2014 04:54:04 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "5312b96c-5ab26c1"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
Length: 95102657 (91M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `xxxx.mkv'

2015-03-14 20:18:19 (195 KB/s) - `xxxx.mkv' saved [95102657/95102657]
```

I am consuming too much space just because of this log if I'm only interested with the real details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off a lot of output with the [`-nv` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-verbose). If that's too little verbosity for you, you can tune the progress report with the [`--progress` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-progress-indicator), but I think you can't remove it altogether. The `dot:mega` report style produces one dot per 64kB (instead of the default with a dot per 1kB).

```
wget --progress=dot:mega …
```

Recent versions also support `dot:giga` (a dot per 1MB).